# Cannot import UMAP due to "ImportError"

Tags: python, error-handling, dependencies

Here's what I did in a new anaconda3 environment:

```
conda install -c conda-forge umap-learn
```

I open jupyter notebook within this environment, and run this to see the python version, which outputs 3.8.3:

```
from platform import python_version
python_version()
```

Then, I tried to run this code via jupyter notebook.

```
import umap.umap_ as umap
```

But, then I get this error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_41308/1565114026.py in <module>
----> 1 import umap.umap_ as umap

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\umap\__init__.py in <module>
      1 from warnings import warn, catch_warnings, simplefilter
----> 2 from .umap_ import UMAP
      3 
      4 try:
      5     with catch_warnings():

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\umap\umap_.py in <module>
     45 )
     46 
---> 47 from pynndescent import NNDescent
     48 from pynndescent.distances import named_distances as pynn_named_distances
     49 from pynndescent.sparse import sparse_named_distances as pynn_sparse_named_distances

ImportError: cannot import name 'NNDescent' from 'pynndescent' (unknown location)
```

So then I tried this:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pynndescent
```

Here's the output for "conda list"

```
(idetc2) C:\Users\User>conda list
# packages in environment at C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\idetc2:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
bzip2                     1.0.8                h8ffe710_4    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2022.4.26            haa95532_0
colorama                  0.4.4              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
intel-openmp              2022.0.0          h57928b3_3663    conda-forge
joblib                    1.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
libblas                   3.9.0              14_win64_mkl    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.9.0              14_win64_mkl    conda-forge
libffi                    3.4.2                h8ffe710_5    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.9.0              14_win64_mkl    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.2.11            h8ffe710_1014    conda-forge
llvmlite                  0.38.0          py310h2c03ce5_1    conda-forge
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6    conda-forge
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7    conda-forge
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7    conda-forge
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2    conda-forge
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2    conda-forge
mkl                       2022.0.0           h0e2418a_796    conda-forge
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1    conda-forge
numba                     0.55.1          py310h77579ad_1    conda-forge
numpy                     1.21.6          py310hcae7c84_0    conda-forge
openssl                   3.0.3                h8ffe710_0    conda-forge
pip                       22.1               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pynndescent               0.5.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
python                    3.10.4          hcf16a7b_0_cpython    conda-forge
python_abi                3.10                    2_cp310    conda-forge
scikit-learn              1.1.0           py310h4dafddf_0    conda-forge
scipy                     1.8.0           py310h33db832_1    conda-forge
setuptools                62.2.0          py310h5588dad_0    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.38.5               h8ffe710_0    conda-forge
tbb                       2021.5.0             h2d74725_1    conda-forge
threadpoolctl             3.1.0              pyh8a188c0_0    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.12               h8ffe710_0    conda-forge
tqdm                      4.64.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tzdata                    2022a                h191b570_0    conda-forge
ucrt                      10.0.20348.0         h57928b3_0    conda-forge
umap-learn                0.5.3           py310h5588dad_0    conda-forge
vc                        14.2                 hb210afc_6    conda-forge
vs2015_runtime            14.29.30037          h902a5da_6    conda-forge
wheel                     0.37.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.5                h62dcd97_1    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.11            h8ffe710_1014    conda-forge
```

And here's the output for "pip list"

```
(idetc2) C:\Users\User>pip list
Package       Version
------------- -------
colorama      0.4.4
joblib        1.1.0
llvmlite      0.38.0
numba         0.55.1
numpy         1.21.6
pip           22.1
pynndescent   0.5.4
scikit-learn  1.1.0
scipy         1.8.0
setuptools    62.2.0
threadpoolctl 3.1.0
tqdm          4.64.0
umap-learn    0.5.3
wheel         0.37.1
```

Not sure what to do at this point. I had created the new environment since I was having other issues with umap-learn in my original environment. The one thing I just noticed is that the python from conda forge is 3.10.4 but the one in my jupyter notebook is 3.8.3. Going to see if upgrading the jupyter notebook python fixes anything.

Would greatly appreciate some suggestions. Thanks!